# Keras: using validation data with fit_generator

Tags: keras

When I use fit_generator in Keras, I get the validation set split into minibatches, and each minibatch is evaluated as training progresses. I want the validation data used exactly once at the end of each epoch. That is, my code is currently:

```
def model_fit_generator(self):
    #This does the actual training of the model

    earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=5, verbose=2, mode='auto')

    self.__model.fit_generator(generator=self.train_generator, 
            validation_data=self.valid_generator, 
            steps_per_epoch=self.s_per_e, 
            epochs=self.epochs,
            validation_steps = self.v_per_e, 
            shuffle=False, 
            verbose=2,
            callbacks=[earlystop])
    model_filename = '_'.join([str(x) for x in now_list]) + '_model.h5'
    self.__model.save(model_filename)

def model_evaluate(self):
    self.model_fit_generator()
    evaluation = self.__model.evaluate_generator(self.valid_generator, self.v_per_e, verbose=0)
    return evaluation
```

How do I change this so that I have the validation data used once, at the end of each epoch, to decide whether early stopping is useful?

EDIT: In response to a comment, here is a complete MWE, showing that the validation data are being used at the same time as the training data. Note this code will produce an error, but it also prints out batch numbers to show that validation and training sets are both being used. To run this code, you will need 10 CSV files of data, which I can provide, but I'd rather just give you the output right after this code.

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

from pandas import concat
from pandas import DataFrame
import sys, keras, GPy, GPyOpt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Model
from keras.metrics import binary_crossentropy
from keras.layers import Dense, Input, LSTM, Lambda
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

class my_model():

    def __init__(self, n_lags=2, hid_dim_1=5, epochs=2, batch_size=1):
        self.n_lags = n_lags
        self.hid_dim_1 = hid_dim_1
        self.epochs = epochs
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.train_generator, self.s_per_e, self.valid_generator, self.v_per_e, self.n_vars = self.read_data()
        self.__model = self.model()

    def read_data(self):

        n_vars = 2
        num_sample_minibatches = 6
        num_valid_minibatches = 4
        sample_IDs = range(1, self.batch_size+num_sample_minibatches)
        valid_IDs = range(num_sample_minibatches+1, max(sample_IDs)+num_valid_minibatches+1)
        params = {'batch_size': self.batch_size, 'n_lags': self.n_lags, 'n_vars': n_vars}
        train_generator = DataGenerator(sample_IDs, **params)
        valid_generator = DataGenerator(valid_IDs, **params)
        s_per_e = int(len(sample_IDs) - self.batch_size + 1) #e.g. if you have 1,2,3,4,5,6 then you can create 4 sequences of length 3 (batch_size)
        v_per_e = int(len(valid_IDs) - self.batch_size + 1)

        return train_generator, s_per_e, valid_generator, v_per_e, n_vars

    def model(self):
        #https://github.com/twairball/keras_lstm_vae/blob/master/lstm_vae/vae.py
        a_input = Input(shape=(self.n_lags, self.n_vars,), name='a_input')
        cond_on_this = Input(shape=(self.n_vars,), name="cond_on_this")
        b_lstm = LSTM(self.hid_dim_1)(a_input)
        outputs = Dense(self.hid_dim_1, activation='sigmoid')(b_lstm)
        my_model1 = Model([a_input, cond_on_this], outputs)
        my_model1.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001), loss=binary_crossentropy)
        return my_model1

    def my_model_fit_generator(self):
        earlystop = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_acc', patience=5, verbose=2, mode='auto')
        self.__model.fit_generator(generator=self.train_generator,
            validation_data=self.valid_generator,
            steps_per_epoch=self.s_per_e,
            epochs=self.epochs,
            validation_steps = self.v_per_e,
            shuffle=False,
            verbose=2,
            callbacks=[earlystop])

    def my_model_evaluate(self):
        self.my_model_fit_generator()
        evaluation = self.__model.evaluate_generator(self.valid_generator, self.v_per_e, verbose=0)
        return evaluation

class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):

    'Generates data for Keras'
    def __init__(self, list_IDs, batch_size, n_lags, n_vars, shuffle=False):
        'Initialization'
        self.list_IDs = list_IDs
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_lags = n_lags
        self.n_vars = n_vars
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.on_epoch_end()

    def __len__(self):
        'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
        batches_per_epoch = int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) - self.batch_size + 1))
        return batches_per_epoch

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        'Generate one batch of data'
        #Here's my evidence that the validation minibatches are being used during training!
        print('batch number: ', index+1, 'of: ', int(np.floor(len(self.list_IDs) - self.batch_size + 1)))
        indexes = self.indexes[index:(index+self.batch_size)]

        # Find list of IDs
        list_IDs_temp = [self.list_IDs[k] for k in indexes]

        # Generate data
        data, cond_on_this = self.__data_generation(list_IDs_temp)

        return [np.asarray(data), np.asarray(cond_on_this)], np.asarray(cond_on_this)

    def on_epoch_end(self):
        'Updates indexes after each epoch'
        self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.list_IDs))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)

    #From MachineLearningMastery
    def series_to_supervised(self, data, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
        n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
        df = DataFrame(data)
        cols, names = list(), list()

        #input sequence t-n, ..., t-1
        for i in range(self.n_lags, 0, -1): #for i in 3 to 0 not including 0
            cols.append(df.shift(i))
            names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range (self.n_vars)]

        #forecast sequence t, t+1, ..., t+n
        for i in range(0, n_out):
            cols.append(df.shift(-i))
            if i==0:
                names += [('var%d(t)' % (j+1)) for j in range(self.n_vars)]
            else:
                names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(self.n_vars)]

        agg = concat(cols, axis=1)
        agg.columns = names
        if dropnan:
            agg.dropna(inplace=True)
        return agg

    def __data_generation(self, list_IDs_temp):
        'Generates data containing batch_size samples'
        data_np_array = np.empty((self.batch_size, self.n_vars), dtype=float)

        for i, ID in enumerate(list_IDs_temp):
            #Read in a data file corresponding to this ID; put it into the numpy array.
            data_file = './pollution_' + str(i) + '.csv'
            df_data = pd.read_csv(data_file, sep=",", header=0)
            df_data.columns = ['date','pollution','dew','temp','press','wnd_dir','wnd_spd','snow','rain']
            df_data_vals = df_data[['pollution', 'temp']] #this is shape (24, 2)
            data_np_array[i,] = np.asarray(df_data_vals)

        data_s2s = np.asarray(self.series_to_supervised(data_np_array))

        data_data = data_s2s[:, :int(self.n_vars*self.n_lags)]
        data_cond = data_s2s[:, int(self.n_vars*self.n_lags):]
        data_data = data_data.reshape((data_data.shape[0], self.n_lags, self.n_vars))

        return data_data, data_cond

def run_my_model(n_lags=2, hid_dim_1=5, epochs=2, batch_size=1):

    _my_model = my_model(n_lags=n_lags, hid_dim_1=hid_dim_1, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size)
    mymodel_evaluation = _my_model.my_model_evaluate()
    return mymodel_evaluation

#Bounds for hyperparameters
bounds = [{'name': 'hid_dim_1', 'type': 'discrete', 'domain': (5, 10)}]

#Bayesian Optimization
def f(x):
    evaluation = run_my_model(hid_dim_1 = int(x[:,0]), epochs = 2, batch_size = 1)
    print("binary crossentropy:\t{0}".format(evaluation[0]))
    print(evaluation)
    return evaluation

#Optimizer instance
opt_mymodel = GPyOpt.methods.BayesianOptimization(f=f, domain=bounds, initial_design_numdata=1)

#Run optimizer
opt_mymodel.run_optimization(max_iter=2)
opt_mymodel.x_opt
```

Relevant Output:

```
Using TensorFlow backend.
Epoch 1/2
batch number:  1 of:  4
batch number:  1 of:  6
batch number:  2 of:  4
batch number:  2 of:  6
batch number:  3 of:  4
batch number:  3 of:  6
batch number:  4batch number:  4 of:   4
of:  6
batch number:  5 of:  6
batch number:  6 of:  6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...Error after this...
```

Comment: The EarlyStopping callback already does this, what is the exact issue you are having?

Comment: The validation set is put into minibatches and evaluated during training; I want it evalulated in minibatches at the end of the epoch.

Comment: No, Keras uses the validation set only at the end of an epoch. What evidence do you have that validation data is being used for training?

Comment: Hi @MatiasValdenegro, please see the edit? Maybe I'm having trouble expressing what's happening.

Comment: Have you noticed that validation metrics are only available at the end of an epoch? My guess is that you see is just keras caching the values from the generator in parallel. Doesn't mean that its being used for training (it makes no sense conceptually).

Comment: Yes, I know they're only available after the end of an epoch, but why doesn't this output mean that Keras is using the validation data at each iteration of training?

Comment: To prove that you would need to point source code in Keras doing it

Comment: To directly answer: correlation doesn't imply causation :)